# Placeholder Plugin - Values are not clearing on form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, placeholder

I am using a placeholder plugin that is working great, aside from the placeholder value being submitted in the form. I am calling the function clearVal() onclick, which I feel should clear all my inputs that have the value equal to that of the placeholder. Thus, these values will not be submitted in the form.

Here is the JQuery:

```
function clearVal() {
var input = $("input[type=text]")
if ($(input).hasClass("placeholder")) {
    input.val("");
}
};
$(function() {
if(typeof document.createElement("input").placeholder == 'undefined') {
    $("[placeholder]").focus(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr("placeholder")) {
            input.val("");
            input.removeClass("placeholder");
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == "" || input.val() == input.attr("placeholder")) {
            input.addClass("placeholder");
            input.val(input.attr("placeholder"));
        }
    }).blur();
}
});
```

Submit Button:

```
<button onclick="clearVal()" id="Submit_Form" type="submit" value="">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var input` is an array of inputs when calling functions like `hasClass` or `val` it will only work for the first item in the list.

instead you should loop through all the elements in the collection.

also it is possible to submit the form without the click event being fired on the button. you should bind to the form's submit event instead

```
 <script>
  $("form").submit(function(e){
     var emptyInputs = $(this).find("input[type='text'].placeholder");
     emptyInputs.each(function(){
          $(this).val("");
      });
      return true;
 });
 </script>
```